# 404 Error.. When manage an existing volume

Tags: openstack, openstack-cinder

I have a question when I try to manage an existing volume using Block Storage API V3.
I made a request to **/v3/{project_id}/manageable_volumes** with the POST method.

But I can’t manage an existing volume.

Looking at the log, there was an error of 404.
It's written in the document, so please tell me the reason for the 404 error.

---

This is the link about api detail.
https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/block-storage/v3/?expanded=manage-an-existing-volume-detail

---

Thank you.

Comment: 404 means "not found", so I guess that the driver doesn't find the storage volume whose reference you provide. My first step would be checking that reference.

Comment: Please add all the information to the question, like the response you get when you list manageable volumes and how exactly you try to manage an existing volume? I get a 404 when I use incorrect syntax.

Comment: when I send 'v3/{project_id}/os-volume-manage', I can manage volume. I think /manageable_volumes api-ref is wrong.